# Nested type constraints with generics

Tags: swift, generics

I'm wondering whether this kind of function definition is possible in swift

Let's say we have this 3 protocols

```
protocol Foo {
    typealias T

    func get(key: String) -> T
}

protocol Bar {
    typealias T: Cacheable

    func set(item: T)
}

protocol Cacheable: NSCoding {
    func getKey() -> String
}
```

Then this two classes

```
class MyClass<T: Cacheable>: Foo, Bar { ... }
class MyOtherClass<T: Cacheable>: Foo, Bar { ... }
```

Imagine that we want a function that can receive an instance of either one of this classes. I can not figure out how to get the signature right, I have tried this that seems logical but it does not work

```
func doThing<T<V> : protocol<Foo, Bar> where V:Cacheable>(instance: T) { ... }
```

Any clue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You want to put a constraint on the placeholder based on its associated type:

```
func doThing
  <U: protocol<Foo, Bar> where U.T: Cacheable>
  (instance: U) {
    // ...
}
```

(You also probably want to avoid giving associated types the name `T` – that’s best left just for placeholders – in theory you could write `T where T.T: Cacheable` but its likely to lead to some horrible confusion at some point.  If this is a container, the convention is `Element`)

Comment: I tried a similar solution before with no luck, the problem is that if you try to pass an instance of a class that implements Cacheable to the set method you get an error

    `func doThing
        <U: protocol<Foo, Bar> where U.T: Cacheable>
        (instance: U) {
            instance.set(CacheableClass(identifier: "1", name: "test1"))
    }`

`Cannot invoke 'set' with an argument list of type '(CacheableClass)'`

Being CacheableClass a class implementing the Cacheable protocol

Comment: Hmm. Can you expand the code in the question so that it’s pasteable into a playground?

Comment: Yeah sorry, hit the Enter button too quickly :D

Comment: Oh I see the problem, there are _two_ `T`s so there’s going to be ambiguity problems.  Might `Bar` really be a refinement of `Foo`?

Comment: I think there’s another SO question somewhere about this issue – but IIRC there wasn’t a solution.

Comment: In the real world usage I have three protocols that should be different. I was wondering this was a limitation of the language at this point and it looks like it. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Solution would be, if `T` really is supposed to be the same thing in both, factor it out into a common base protocol (and then add extra constraints in `Foo`).  If the two `T` are different, only solution is to give them distinct names I believe.